# Is using build variables in localized InfoPlist.strings possible?

Tags: xcode, configuration, build-process

I'd like to distinguish Debug, Beta and App Store builds of my app like it's described [here](http://swwritings.com/post/2013-05-20-concurrent-debug-beta-app-store-builds). This works fine and I have all the build variables in place, but the CFBundleDisplayName of my app is localized into two different languages. Adding the ${BUNDLE_DISPLAY_NAME_SUFFIX} to my Info.plist apparently doesn't do anything and using the variable inside the localized string treats it as a regular string.

So I was wondering if it is even possible to reference a build variable from the InfoPlist.strings files or if I have overlooked something. Do I have to use a distinct build script for that or is this plainly not an out-of-the-box possibility?